# Python: elegant and save coding way to create several list

Tags: python, list, optimization, coding-style

Normally in order to store result in several lists in python, i create before the loop the corresponding empty lists.

```
A = []
B = []
c = []
D = []
E = []
F = []

for i in range(100):
  # do some stuff
```

i there a method to create the lists in a single code line (or few)?

Comment: Thanks Alexvassel, the problem is my lists are 100

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the lists are logically similar (I hope so, because one hundred different variables is violence on programmer), create a dictionary of lists:

```
list_names = ['a', 'b', 'c' ]
d = {name:[] for name in list_names}
```

This creates a dictionary:

```
d = {'a': [], 'b': [], 'c': []}
```

where you can access individual lists:

```
d['a'].append(...)
```

or work on all of them at once:

```
for v in d.itervalues():
    v.append(...)
```

The further advantage over individual lists is that you can pass your whole dict to a method.

Comment: or simply `defaultdict(list)`

Comment: @thg435 - not simply… because if you call `d['xxx']` with `defaultdict`, it returns an empty list, although you have never explicitely defined it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an object:

```
>>> from string import ascii_uppercase
>>> class MyLists(object):
    def __init__(self):
        for char in ascii_uppercase:
            setattr(self, char, [])


>>> l = MyLists()
>>> l.A
[]
>>> l.B
[]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a, b, c, d, e, f = [], [], [], [], [], []
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lists = ([] for _ in range(6))
lists[5].append(...)
```

or

```
A, B, C, D, E, F = ([] for _ in range(6))
```

or with defaultdict

```
d = defaultdict(list)
d['F'].append(...)
```